# Paypal buynow button not working

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

I just tried to implement paypal buynow button, however when I add this to my page:

```
<script src="www/js/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=...my merchant id..." data-button="buynow" data-quantity="1000" data-amount="100" data-currency="CZK"></script>
```

it just produces this:

```
<div class="paypal-button-widget">
    <button class="paypal-button paypal-style-primary paypal-size-large" type="submit">
        <span class="paypal-button-logo">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,iV...">
        </span>
        <span class="paypal-button-content">Buy with <img src="data:image/png;base64,iV..." alt="PayPal">
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

the button is not wrapped in any  and nothing happens when clicked. Paypal documentation says that just generating the button this way is enough. Can you please tell me what could be the mistake? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the link below to create Buy Now button on your PayPal account.

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/get-started/buy-now-button

For the more details about PayPal Buy Now button, you can go to the link below.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buynow_buttons/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.